# Get all Foreign Keys for All dependent tables for One Table to nth Level

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, foreign-keys, truncate

I have one table Called `Member` with Column Name `Member_Id`.

This Table Referred by more than 23 other tables as Primary Table with `Member_Id` as Foreign Column.

Now these 23 tables also have Primary Keys, and some serve also as Primary table for other tables.

So I want to fetch all Foreign Keys for all dependent Table referring to table `Member`.

My Goal is to Truncate `Member` table which has Foreign keys. I can't use Delete as these tables have more data, so it may take ages for me to delete the data.

For Example:-

Member --> Member-ID

`Member-Contact` connect with `Member` table Using Member_ID, Primary Key `Contact_No`
`Member_Population` connect with `Member` table Using Member_ID, Primary Key `population_seq_no`

...23 More

These `Member-Contact`, `Member_Population` and 23 more also have dependent tables with other tables as Foreign Keys.

So before truncate I need to Drop All Foreign Keys then Truncate All these dependent tables then Restore these foreign keys.

Till now I write this query which fetch all Foreign Keys for one table

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() Over(Order BY f.parent_object_id) as RowID,
        OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) TableName,
        COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id,fc.parent_column_id) ColName,
        f.name as FKConstraintName,
        COL_NAME(fc.referenced_object_id,fc.referenced_column_id) as ReferenceColName
--INTO  #temp_ReferenceContstraints     
FROM    sys.foreign_keys AS f
        INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc ON f.OBJECT_ID = fc.constraint_object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON t.OBJECT_ID = fc.referenced_object_id
WHERE   OBJECT_NAME (f.referenced_object_id) = 'Member'
```

I want to find all foreign keys for all dependent tables?

Comment: why you don't use user interface for all dependent tables in `sql server` ?

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/02/04/sql-server-get-the-list-of-object-dependencies-sp_depends-and-information_schema-routines-and-sys-dm_sql_referencing_entities/

Comment: Well you could take the results of the query you have, run a cursor over the results and run the same query over each of those tables; and you can set it up recursively so it goes to the Nth level.

Comment: Ok, so instead of recursively calling the SP, put the recursive cursor in the SP, so you only call it once.   Or do it in a script without any SP's.   Especially if this is a one-off.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
 ;
 WITH fkey 
 as (
      select   constraint_id = f.object_id
        ,      constraint_name = f.name
        ,      parent_object_id
        ,      parent_name = object_name(f.parent_object_id)
        ,      referenced_object_id
        ,      referenced_object_name = object_name(f.referenced_object_id)
      from     sys.foreign_keys f
 )
 ,  recurse
 as (
      select   depth = 1
         ,     *
      from     fkey
      where    referenced_object_name = 'myTable'  -- <-- use this to filter results.
      union all
      select   depth = recurse.depth + 1
        ,      fkey.*
      from     fkey
         join  recurse 
            on fkey.referenced_object_id = recurse.parent_object_id
 )
 ,  recurseWithFields
 as (
      select   r.*
            ,  parent_column_id
            ,  parent_column_name = p_ac.name
            ,  referenced_column_id
            ,  reference_column_name = r_ac.name
      from     recurse r
          join sys.foreign_key_columns fc
            on r.constraint_id = fc.constraint_object_id
          join sys.all_columns p_ac
            on fc.parent_column_id = p_ac.column_id
            and fc.parent_object_id = p_ac.object_id
          join sys.all_columns r_ac
            on  fc.referenced_column_id = r_ac.column_id
            and fc.referenced_object_id = r_ac.object_id
 )
 select *
 from   recurseWithFields
```

If you want to get all the tables related to a particular table, you need to filter in the CTE called `recurse`, in the location indicated by the comment.

Comment: @Piyush  I didn't do anything to handle it, but if you have any foreign keys from a table to itself, you could get some "runaway recursion".  You might have to put a where clause in `fkey` to prevent it:  `where parent_object_id <> referenced_object_id`.