# SQL Server : the maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-hints

I have a query that is returning an error with the maximum levels of recursion exceeded.

I know how to fix this by adding `OPTION (maxrecursion 0)` to the query however, I have tried adding this at various places in the query and I cant find where to put it where the syntax is valid.

Can anyone give me any pointers as to where in my view the query hint needs to be inserted?

```
/****** Object:  View [dbo].[SiconCFMContractLinesDetailByDayView]    Script Date: 16/12/2016 12:02:35 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[SiconCFMContractLinesDetailByDayView]
AS
WITH dateRange as
(
SELECT      [Date] = DATEADD(dd, 1, DATEADD(dd, -1,[SiconCFMContractLinesOutstandingView].[NextDueDate])),
[Frequency] = [SiconCFMContractLinesOutstandingView].[FrequencyValue],
[EndDate] = DATEADD(yy,5, [SiconCFMContractLinesOutstandingView].[NextDueDate]),
[SiconCFMContractLinesOutstandingView].[SiconContractLineID]
FROM        [SiconCFMContractLinesOutstandingView]
WHERE       DATEADD(mm, [SiconCFMContractLinesOutstandingView].[FrequencyValue], [SiconCFMContractLinesOutstandingView].[NextDueDate]) < DATEADD(mm, [SiconCFMContractLinesOutstandingView].[FrequencyValue], DATEADD(yy,5, [SiconCFMContractLinesOutstandingView].[NextDueDate]))
UNION ALL
SELECT      DATEADD(mm, [Frequency], [Date]) [Date],
[Frequency],
[EndDate],
[SiconContractLineID]
FROM        dateRange
WHERE       DATEADD(mm, [Frequency], [Date]) < DATEADD(mm, [Frequency],[EndDate])

)

SELECT
(
SELECT CASE
WHEN dbo.fnSiconCFMGetSettingValue('UseAverageTimeToPay') = 'True'
THEN
CASE [SiconCFMSLCustomerAverageTimeToPayView].[AvgTimeToPayDateLastUpdated]
WHEN NULL THEN dbo.fnSiconCFMDateByPaymentTerms([SLCustomerAccount].[SYSPaymentTermsBasisID], [SLCustomerAccount].[PaymentTermsInDays], dateRange.[Date])
ELSE DATEADD([DD],[SiconCFMSLCustomerAverageTimeToPayView].[Days],dateRange.[Date])
END
ELSE dbo.fnSiconCFMDateByPaymentTerms([SLCustomerAccount].[SYSPaymentTermsBasisID], [SLCustomerAccount].[PaymentTermsInDays], dateRange.[Date])
END
)
AS [DueDate],
[StockItem].[Name] AS [Title],
[SiconCFMContractLinesOutstandingView].[Description] AS [Description],
[SiconCFMContractLinesOutstandingView].[UnitBillCoverPriceIncDisc] AS [Value],
[SiconCFMContractLinesOutstandingView].[SiconContractID],
[SiconCFMContractLinesOutstandingView].[SiconContractLineID],
[SiconCFMContractLinesOutstandingView].[SiconContractLineID] AS [ForecastDateForeignID],
'SiconContractLine' AS [ForecastDateSource],
(
SELECT
CASE WHEN EXISTS
(
SELECT [SiconCFMMemo].[SiconCFMMemoID]
FROM   [SiconCFMMemo]
WHERE  [SiconCFMMemo].[Deleted]=0
AND    [SiconCFMMemo].[IsActive]=1
AND    [SiconCFMMemo].[MemoSource]='SiconContractLine'
AND    [SiconCFMMemo].[MemoForeignID]=[SiconCFMContractLinesOutstandingView].[SiconContractLineID]
)
THEN 1
ELSE 0
END
) AS [HasMemos]
FROM            dateRange 
INNER JOIN      [SiconCFMContractLinesOutstandingView]
ON              dateRange.[SiconContractLineID]
=               [SiconCFMContractLinesOutstandingView].[siconContractLineID]
INNER JOIN      [StockItem]
ON              [StockItem].[ItemID]
=               [SiconCFMContractLinesOutstandingView].[ItemID]
INNER JOIN      [SLCustomerAccount]
ON              [SLCustomerAccount].[SLCustomerAccountID]
=               [SiconCFMContractLinesOutstandingView].[SLCustomerAccountID]
INNER JOIN      [SiconCFMSLCustomerAverageTimeToPayView]
ON              [SiconCFMSLCustomerAverageTimeToPayView].[SLCustomerAccountID]
=               [SLCustomerAccount].[SLCustomerAccountID]
GO
```

as suggested I have added **OPTION (maxrecursion 0)** to just above the last GO statement, however when within the create view statement it is giving a syntax error. If I run the query on its own, outside of a create view statement it works

Comment: At the end of the select statement that uses the recurcive cte

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, At the end of the select statement that uses the recurcive cte.
However, inside a view that will not work.
A quick search got me to [this post](http://benchmarkitconsulting.com/colin-stasiuk/2010/04/12/maxrecursion-with-a-cte-in-a-view/) - that explains the correct way to do it.

Turns out you can't use the query hint inside the view, but you can and should use it in the query that calls the view.

Sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
    id int,
    parent int
)
INSERT INTO T VALUES (1, NULL), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 2), (5, 2), (6, 3), (7, 4), (8, 5);
GO
```

Create the view:

```
CREATE VIEW V
AS

WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT id, parent
    FROM T 
    WHERE parent IS NULL
    UNION ALL

    SELECT t.id, t.parent
    FROM T
    INNER JOIN CTE ON t.parent = cte.id
)

SELECT *
FROM CTE

GO
```

Execute the view:

```
SELECT *
FROM V
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 2);
```

Comment: Thanks, that works if I run the query on its own, however, when i put it in a CreateView statement its coming back with a syntax error, I have updated the question query statement to include all of the code

Comment: Thanks, Ill work my way up the chain of views until I find where it needs to go, its being called from a stored procedure at the top level that takes two parameters for the date range. I have a max recursion hint already on the dates table it pivots on, so it sounds like i need another on the view that is being pivoted with.

Answer (score 0):

there is a very nice script that I use to [check foreign keys recursively by Ann Lewkowicz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29034281/1501497)

However, I once had a database which had plenty of constraints, including foreign key constraints in some of the tables.

and while running the script above I got the following error:

> The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 32767 has been
>   exhausted before statement completion.

then I limited the output of the script using `top` and it all went out fine

```
 select top 100 *
 from   recurseWithFields 
--OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767);
```